# Postgres Log Error

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, geowebcache

I am using Geoserver + GeoWebCache + Postgres for an application. On the application side there is no bugs but on postgres I am getting this log. Please explain and help me to solve this

> 2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST ERROR:  relation "public.gt_pk_metadata" does not exist at character 15
>   2014-03-14 10:14:50 IST STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM public.GT_PK_METADATA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table or view named GT_PK_METADA in public shema does not exists in your database. Postgresql uses lower cases by default. So if you have GT_PK_METADATA in your database your query should be `SELECT * FROM public."GT_PK_METADATA"`

Answer (score 12):

The table gt_pk_metadata is an optional table that GeoTools (and GeoServer) use to work out what the primary key columns in a view are. It is needed to generate consistent feature IDs (FIDS) otherwise GeoTools will use the feature's java ID which will change from run to run.

It is explained in this [document](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html). So you can ignore this error if you don't care about consistent feature IDs (FIDS) across server restarts.